# UIWebView browser size does not match its frame size

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiwebview, frame

I've created a UIWebView and I load this link: "https://www.whatismybrowser.com/".

but I always get 768 on iPad no matter what frame size ! I set the web view to 200 x 200 but the pages get 768 x 200 meaning that height is the actual frame size but width is always a full iPad page. How do I change this?

Thanks,
Peyman

Comment: Are you looking under “YOUR BROWSER'S SIZE” or “YOUR COMPUTER SCREEN”?

Comment: YOUR BROWSER'S SIZE. Computer screen shouldn't change when I change frame and it doesn't.

Comment: Why do you need a website to tell you your size of browser? Could you not use the frame of the web view itself rather than an external site telling you?

Comment: @StePrescott The issue here is that external websites don't get correct frame size. My frame size is 200 x 200 but websites get 768 x 200 which is incorrect so they prepare the layout based on width of 768 (if they're responsive) and then user needs to scroll to see the whole content while if websites gets informed that width is 200 not 768, it'll layout itself for a 200 frame.

Comment: @peyman Have you tried it out on a responsive site other than the one you have given above?